# EF Core - Add unique index

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I´m doing a CRUD of countries and cities and I´m trying to add a unique index to City.Name.

I already did that to Country.Name and I would like to know if it´s possible to do that to a city so that 2 cities in 2 countries can have the same Name but in 1 country there cannot be any cities with repeated names.

**Country Class**

```
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }

public ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
```

**City Class**

```
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

When I create a city I´m using this ViewModel

**CityViewModel**

```
public int CountryId { get; set; }


public int CityId { get; set; }


[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

**OnModelCreating**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().HasIndex(c => c.Name).IsUnique();

     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

**Example**

Let´s say I have 2 countries Canada and Australia and inside Canada I have 1 city named Sydney.

If I try to create or edit another country so it gets named Canada or Australia, I want it to give an error.

If I try to create or edit another city so it gets named Sydney, if the city is created in the country Australia it should not give an error but if it´s created in the country Canada it should give an error.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Can you include an example of the data you'd like to allow and the data you don't want to?

Comment: @ESG I have included an example I hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need 2 unique indices.

To prevent multiple countries to have the same name, you need a unique index in its name:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().HasIndex(c => c.Name ).IsUnique();
```

If you also want to prevent multiple cities in the same country to have the same names, assuming that you have a country id (or code) in the Cities table, you can can create an index on multiple columns:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<City>().HasIndex(c => new { c.Name, c.CountryId }).IsUnique();
```

Comment: I tried and now I can insert a country with a name that already exists and about the city it stayed the same

Comment: @ESG you should put that index on the `City` entity, not `Country`

Comment: @ESG It does create a column countryId in the table Cities but I can´t do that index to the City because I don´t have a property named CountryId in my class City.

Comment: @AndréMartins The way you have your model setup now, it looks like you've having an implied property that EF builds behind the scene. You might have to add CountryId to your City model to achieve your goal